# How to implement a barcode scanner for Blackberry?

Tags: java, blackberry, barcode

I have to implement a barcode scanner for my application. I want to use zxing to do my work.

I can't simply create a UIApplication, cause my app is also for no Blackberry devices (but barcode reader is only for BB)

I have read a lot of examples, but I think that I need specific help:

I have implemented a midlet for BB9700: when user press a button,

1) camera app is called (and my midlet go in background mode)
 2) user take a photo to a datamatrix image
 3) when user return back, my app is active and try to detect the barcode result.

The main class implements FileSystemJournalListener, so when a file is added this class process it in this way:

```java
EncodedImage encodedImage = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
Bitmap bmp = encodedImage.getBitmap();
DataMatrixReader reader = new DataMatrixReader();
LuminanceSource source = new BitmapLuminanceSource(bmp);
BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new GlobalHistogramBinarizer(source));
result = reader.decode(bitmap);
```

Every time I try to decode the image, a ReaderException is thrown.

The picture I take by using camera is perfect, and also the image is correctly processed (I hae print it onscreen for test and picture is ok).

Why I can't got the correct result? I am correctly using the `zxing` lib?

I have also seen the `HybridGinarizer`, but unfortunately `zxing` version I'm using is a little bit old.

Do I simply update `zxing` lib and use the `HibridBinarizer`?

Comment: Did you see the BarcodeDemo which is provided by Version 6.0...?

Answer (score 0):

`ReaderException` is normal and just means that particular image couldn't be decoded. Your code may or may not be OK. If no images work then something's probably wrong with your code.

You should really use the most recent verison, not the one in the BB SDK.

Answer (score -1):

Even I'm not familiar with development of Blackberry, I have an idea to get a step closer to the solution.

Everything in Java that can be thrown must derive from [java.lang.Throwable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html). Therefore, even your `ReaderException` you're getting should have a method called `getMessage()`.

Maybe you could now try to catch the exception and print the message on the UI? Maybe the library you're using is giving more information there... If you have some IDE like eclipse **and** the possibility to attach the debugger to an app running on your BlackBerry, things get easier.